# refrence values betweeen models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 2 models in Django(one to many). Customer and Address. I need to store these values into a 3rd part end point in one API call. Also from the response I need to store the returned ids as Pk and Fk's in my DB.

When i call is_valid is when I would like to do the API calls since I can raise the error returned by third parts as part of validation exercise. Is there a way in which I can do the validation and Api call in just 1 is_valid method?

Basically can I access address model object/values when I am in clean() for addresss so that I can create 1 payload and then send it to 3rd party?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more detail example? i.e. your models and forms

Comment: Sure, I have following for customer and address:
- Each has a model, form class and a clean method. 
 return render(request, 'nscustomerentry.html', {'nsCreateCustomer':form, 'addrForm': addressForm})

Comment: Now the issue is when I do clean, I can only validate 1 model since I would like to post the data to 3rd part and return form error if any errors were returned. I would like to send both pieces together as payload as part of clean so that I can raise erorrs if any. Hope this helps.